# How to select a input from parent and get the value of input?

Tags: jquery

I am rendering a table row by row from the result array retried from ajax post, and each row have column calls menu I rendered it by function `getActionMenu` where the parent is a `<td>` and in this `menu` column.

I dynamically create one input text box `<input type="number" class="input-mini maxStuNum">` and a button `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SUBMIT</button>`. When I hit the button, I am serach from self up to its parent then find the input by classname `.maxStuNum` to try to get its value and do further.

However, Chrome always says `maxStuNum` is Undefined.

From debug console I do see seems the input `class="maxStuNum"` is already found. But I don't know what's the meaning of `input: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]`

Debug:

```
input: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]

0: input.input-mini maxStuNum



    function doSubmit(event){
        var tutor = event.data.row;
        var input = $(this).parent().children(".maxStuNum");
        var maxStuNum = input.attr('value');

    }

    function getActionMenu(row, parent){

        var div = $('<div class="input-append">');
        var input = $('<input type="number" class="input-mini maxStuNum">');

        input.attr('value',row.maxStuNum);
        var btn =$('<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SUBMIT</button>').unbind().bind('click', {'row':row}, doSubmit);;
        div.append(input);
        div.append(btn);
        parent.append(div);
    }
```

Comment: `var maxStuNum = $(this).siblings('.maxStuNum').val();` or if it's not the immediate child of the parent, use find() -> `var maxStuNum = $(this).parent().find(".maxStuNum").val()`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: thank you, Adeneo, it works! I am the newer to use jquery, don't know why my way is not work.

Comment: oh, maybe beacause I missed the ".val()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine except this line

```
var maxStuNum =input.attr('value');
```

use

```
var maxStuNum = input.val();
```